# How to put 'is not null' parameter in Laravel 4 validator for uniqueness

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

For an extended use case for a user signup process, I need to allow emails to be taken which are not confirmed yet. That means the emails that are not yet confirmed are considered open.

In `users` table I use `confirmed_at` field to denote if an email is confirmed or not. If the field is `null` then it's not confirmed. Otherwise there'll be a date.

I am trying out with this:

```
    $v = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
        'email'         => 'required|email|unique:users,email,NULL,confirmed_at',
        'password'      => 'required|confirmed|min:6|max:32',
    ));
```

This results in the following query:

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = 'email@gmail.com'
```

Surprisingly it's not even taking the `confirmed_at` field in.

Although the [doc](http://laravel.com/docs/validation) doesn't say about a predefined id field as second parameter, I tried my luck with the following:

```
$v = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,0,id,confirmed_at,NULL',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6|max:32',
        ));
```

Now it includes the other parameters in the query and results into:

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = 'email@gmail.com' and `id` <> '0' and `confirmed_at` is null
```

But it employs not equal for the first id field but equal for the confirmed_at field.

So, my first question is, how can I get `confirmed_at is not null` in to the query?

And secondly, how possibly I could get rid of `id <> 0` which I had to add although I don't need it?

Comment: Why would you want to add multiple users with the same email address if the are not confirmed but not when there is one confirmed. More useful would be to let users reset their password with a password reset email if they try to sign up with the same email address again.

Comment: The requirement specifier wants to allow the emails that are not confirmed to be treated as not taken. One of the benefits of this is one can't block others emails. The way may be debated, but i am more interested about the technical part of it as I've posted.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution without a custom validator? I'm having a similar issue with my API. I would like to check if the deleted_at field has a timestamp. If so, I want to restore the record, if not create it. This is an big issue for the pivot tables. But if I must I'll create a custom validator. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use `Custom Validators`

An example for your use case:

```
Validator::extend('unconfirmed', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    return (boolean)DB::table('users')->where('confirmed', 'is not', null)->count();
});
```

More information in the official documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: This was my fall back solution already. My question was a little different though, how to get it directly. But I don't think there's any option provided by Laravel as of now. I'll accept your answer as this is seems the only possible way to achieve this. Thank you.